# Getting Assertion error when emit a state in aysnc function in Flutter bloc

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

```
Future<void> fetchInitialData(FetchInitialDataEvent event, Emitter<WalletState> emit) async {
    if (wallets != null) {
      emit(WalletListState(wallets: wallets!));
    } else {
      walletsModel = await getWallets();
      assetsModel = await getSupportedAssets();
      cmc = await getCmc();
      currencies = await getCurrencies();

      fetchAddress();

      wallets = walletEngine.buildWallet(assetsModel, walletsModel, cmc);
      if (wallets != null && configEngine.filteredMarkets == null && configEngine.orgMarkets != null) {
        configEngine.filteredMarkets = walletEngine.filterMarket(wallets!, configEngine.orgMarkets!);
        openSocket.init(configEngine.filteredMarkets!);
      }
      emit(WalletListState(wallets: wallets!));
    }

    if (currencies != null) {
      listenTickerStream(currencies!, coins);
    }
    startWalletScheduler(emit);
  }

startWalletScheduler(Emitter<WalletState> emit) {
    if (walletScheduler?.isActive != true) {
      Duration interval = Duration(seconds: walletIntervalSeconds);
      walletScheduler = Timer.periodic(interval, (timer) async {
        await periodicFetch(emit);
      });
    }
  }

  Future<void> periodicFetch(Emitter<WalletState> emit) async {
    walletsModel = await getWallets();
    wallets = walletEngine.buildWallet(assetsModel, walletsModel, cmc);
    emit(WalletListState(wallets: wallets!));
  }

Future<WalletsResponse?> getWallets() async {
    final result = await repo.wallets(cancelToken: cancelToken);

    return result.fold((error) {
      return Future.value(null);
    }, (resp) {
      return resp;
    });
  }
```

getCmc and getCurrencies are in the same structure as getWallets(). When i execute this code, I am getting the below error

_AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:51:61)
[ ] I/flutter ( 8440): #1 _AssertionError._throwNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:40:5)
[ ] I/flutter ( 8440): #2 _Emitter.call (package:bloc/src/emitter.dart:114:7)
[ ] I/flutter ( 8440): #3 WalletBloc.periodicFetch (package:drip_mobile/src/core/wallet/biz/wallet_bloc.dart:122:9)
[ ] I/flutter ( 8440):
[ ] I/flutter ( 8440): #4 WalletBloc.startWalletScheduler. (package:drip_mobile/src/core/wallet/biz/wallet_bloc.dart:114:9)
[ ] I/flutter ( 8440):

This error is happening during emit(WalletListState(wallets: wallets!)); inside periodicFetch(). What am i doing wrong here? How to efficiently use emit in async functions?

Comment: inside `periodicFetch` you should call [add](https://pub.dev/documentation/bloc/latest/bloc/Bloc/add.html) and not `emit`

Comment: and here some code samples on how to do that: https://bloclibrary.dev/#/fluttertimertutorial

Comment: Thanks, it worked after adding a new event and calling periodicfetch inside the new event.